# \HttpException while trying to query the database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using this ajax call

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{URL::to('/search/mask/byID')}}",
            type: "post",
            data: {value:value},
            success: function (response) {

                console.log(response);

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

And this is the controller

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {

        $maskID = 'Mask_' . $request->input('value');

        $result = masks::where('MaskName', 'LIKE', $maskID)->get();

        return $result;

    }
```

And this is my route:
`Route::post('/search/mask/byID', 'MaskSearchController@search');`

I am getting HTTP 419 in Network tab once the ajax runs, and this is what I see at the response `Route::post('/search/mask/byID', 'MaskSearchController@search');`

The message is empty so I have NO Idea what could cause this :?
I also have

```
$.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
      });
```

and the route is POST, so I don't send POST to GET.

Fixed, I forgot to add the meta

Comment: Try to dd() $maskId and/or $result, see what comes up.

Comment: http://getstatuscode.com/419 ... your token a bit stale perhaps?

Comment: @CBroe What do you mean? :/

Comment: @OmarTarek even if I dd, in the ajax I get the same thing, 419, no message, if I make a view and go on the page, it works, so there is no issue with the database or the eloquent, the issue happens between the ajax and the file and I don't understand what... there is no message...

Comment: Quote from posted link, _"Not a part of the HTTP standard, 419 Authentication Timeout denotes that previously valid authentication has expired. It is used as an alternative to 401 Unauthorized in order to differentiate from otherwise authenticated clients being denied access to specific server resources."_ So far, the only thing in what you have shown us that comes close to count as "Authentication" of sorts, is the CSRF token. Add "Timeout" to that, and it might simply be the server telling you that said token has expired/been invalidated, and you got's to go get yourself a fresh one first.

Comment: I was missing `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`... fixed

Answer (score 0):

first check whether your routes are in routes/api.php only not in routes/web.php.